# Redirect URI error while integrating instagram in iPhone

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, instagram

I'm developing an app where I want to integrate Instagram. I'm able to login to I get Redirect URI error. I'm not able to find out wat exactly the error is. I'm getting

```
{"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message":
"Redirect URI does not match registered redirect uri"}
```

I have also made changes in apps plist list.
I added ig[clientid] as the redirect uri ,where "[clientid]" is my CLIENT ID. While registering for the app I added https://www.bcod.co.in as redirect URI

Comment: How?? Plz Help me.... same problem

Comment: while registering the app you need to provide correct redirect uri ie your clientId and then write authorize

Comment: same problem here but it couldn't be solved even after I set the URI in their website, here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37898044/instagram-api-prevents-redirection-to-ios-app-upon-successful-login